# How do I insert vertical space into a PDF document using ODS PDF?

Tags: sas

I'm using ODS PDF to create a simple PDF report, but I'm having trouble inserting space between the tables into the PDF file. This is the code so far:

```
ODS PDF FILE = "test.pdf" STARTPAGE = NEVER;

DATA CLINIC;
   INPUT ID     $ 1-3
         GENDER $   4
         RACE   $   5
         HR       6-8
         SBP      9-11
         DBP     12-14
         N_PROC  15-16;
   AVE_BP = DBP + (SBP - DBP)/3;
DATALINES;
001MW08013008010
002FW08811007205
003MB05018810002
004FB   10806801
005MW06812208204
006FB101   07404
007FW07810406603
008MW04811207006
009FB07719011009
010FB06616410610
;


ODS PDF TEXT = "MEANS PROCEDURE FOR EVERYONE";
PROC MEANS DATA=CLINIC N STD MEAN;
    VAR SBP DBP;
RUN;

ODS PDF TEXT = "TEXT FOR ANALYSIS GOES HERE";

* Vertical space should be inserted here;

ODS PDF TEXT = "MEANS PROCEDURE FOR MEN ONLY";
PROC MEANS DATA=CLINIC N STD MEAN;
    WHERE GENDER = "M";
    VAR SBP DBP;
RUN;
ODS PDF TEXT = "TEXT FOR ANALYSIS GOES HERE";

ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

I know that if I remove `STARTPAGE = NEVER;` the tables will appear on separate pages, but since these are short tables, it doesn't make sense to have each small table on a separate page.

I'm just trying to insert some vertical space into the file where the comments indicate (between the text after the first table and the text before the first table). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add some newlines like:

```
ods pdf text="^{newline 1}";
```

The `1` can be replaced with how many lines of white space you want added.

This is assuming your escape character is the same as mine. If not, set it like:

```
ods escapechar="^";
```